# VSCode set shortcut "when" context to detect set breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I'm trying to set a keyboard shortcut for the command `python.debugInTerminal` on Visual Studio Code, but I would like it to run only when a breakpoint is **created** in the file. Inversely, if there are no set breakpoints in the file, this command should not run.

Is there a "when" context term to define this? For example, there is one called `breakpointsFocused`, but I dont think this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `breakpointsExist` true/false context key.

Open the Developer Tools/Console and then invoke the command

`Developer: Inspect Context Keys`

and click anywhere in vscode.  Then in the Console open up the last object which should have a long list of available context keys.  Search for `breakpoint` and there are a few.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, this is exactly what I was looking for!